# To prove that $(\mathbb{P(N)},d)$ is a metric space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, natural-numbers

To prove that $(\mathbb{P(N)},d)$ is a metric space where $\mathbb{P(N)}$ is the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.  And $d:\mathbb{P(N)}\times \mathbb{P(N)} \mapsto\mathbb{R}$ is defined by
$d(A,B)=\begin{cases} 0, & \text{if A} \Delta \text{B=}\emptyset  \\ m^{-1}, & \text{where m is the smallest member of} A\Delta B \end{cases} $.

Attempt: $x \in P\Delta Q=(P-Q)\cup(Q-P) \implies x\in (P-Q) \text{ or } x\in (Q-P) $. But $(P-Q)\cap(Q-P)= \emptyset \implies x \in P \text{ and} \notin Q \text{ or }x \in Q \text{ and} \notin P. \ \ \ $    (*)

To prove the triangle inequality:

Take any three sets $A,B,C \subset \mathbb{P(N)}$ such that none of them are equal to another. Now,

$\min A \Delta B  =m_1, \min B \Delta C  =m_2,  \min A \Delta C  =m_3   $. To prove $d(A,B) \leq d(A,C)+ d(B,C)$. By (*), $m_1 \in A$ or $m_1 \in B$ but not both.

Again,  $m_2 \leq m_1$  or $m_3 \leq m_1$. Either way, we are done. When $A \neq B$ and either $B =C $ or $A=C$ (not both), we have respectively $A=C$ , $B=C$ . Which satisfies the triangle inequality. When $A=B$ it is evident.

Symmetry: We know $A \Delta B =B \Delta A$. $d(A,B)= d(B,A)$

Non-negativity and $0 \iff A=B$:

$d(A,B)=0 \iff A \Delta B= \emptyset \iff A \subset B \text{ and } B \subset A \iff A=B$. By definition $d(A,B) \geq 0$

Is this okay? Please verify.

Comment: Why do we get ($m_2\le m_1$ or $m_3\le m_1$)?

Comment: @Berci Let $m_1 \in A.$  Now, if $m_1\in A\Delta C$, we are done. Now if $m_1 \in A\cap C$, we have either $< m_3$ or $\geq m_3$. In the latter case, there is nothing to prove. 

To resolve the case when $m_1 <m_3$: Since $m_1 \notin B$, $m_1 \in B \Delta C$. Consequently $m_2 \leq m_1$

Comment: Ok, that convinced me.

Answer (score 3):

Use that $A \Delta C\subseteq (A \Delta B) \cup (B \Delta C)$, so $\min(A\Delta C) \ge \min(\min(A \Delta B), \min(B \Delta C))$ and so (as $m \to \frac1m$ reverses order) $d(A,C) \le \max(d(A,B), d(B,C))$ which shows that $d$ is even an *[ultrametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space)*.

I don't see why $m_2 \le m_1$ or $m_3 \le m_1$ is justified, you give no argument for that. I concur symmetry and the remaining axioms are all trivial.

Comment: Let $m_1 \in A.$  Now, if $m_1\in A\Delta C$, we are done. Now if $m_1 \in A\cap C$, we have either $< m_3$ or $\geq m_3$. In the latter case, there is nothing to prove. 

To resolve the case when $m_1 <m_3$: Since $m_1 \notin B$, $m_1 \in B \Delta C$. Consequently $m_2 \leq m_1$

Is this a proper justification?

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas Almost, you're still missing some cases..

Comment: The case is similar for $m_1 \in B$. What other cases am I missing?

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas then add $m_1 \in B$ too..

Comment: Ok: 
 On the other hand, if $m_1 \in B$ then $m_1 \notin A$. If $m_1 \in B \Delta C$, $ m_2 \leq m_1 $. If $m_1 \in B\cap C$, $m_1 \geq m_2 \text{ or } m_1<m_2$. Then for the latter $m_1 \in A \Delta C$, consequently $m_3 \leq m_1$

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas You're basically reproving the inclusion I also use at the start, aren't you? Then do that too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98395/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-henno-brandsma).